# Apply bi-lineal filter on geometry drawn on a map

Tags: openlayers

I am drawing about 1000 contiguous polygons (rectangles) on a map, with different colours depending on a value in that location.

[image]

To render this I am using an ol.layer.vector, where mypolygons is an array that contains rectangles, and the colour varies per rectangle/span:

```
var polygonLayer = new LayerVector({
    source: new SourceVector({
        overlaps: false,
        features: mypolygons
    })};
map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
```

The problem is that when I zoom in, the edges between the polygons appear very sharp.

Is there a way to smooth the edges? Maybe some way to render these polygons into a low-res canvas layer that gets projected on the map, enlarged using bi-lineal filtering?

Comment: Please edit your question and post a picture of what you have and what would you like to have.

Comment: You could apply a filter to the layer as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/semi-transparent-layer.html

Comment: I just added a picture of the issue.

Comment: Did you try Mike's suggestion?

Comment: I don't see how that would help implement upsampling with bi-lineal filtering, or some kind of gaussian blur.

Comment: If you don't try you won't see, that's true. CSS blur filter applies just Gaussian blur.

Comment: Ah, awesome! I was not aware of that CSS filter. This looks great. Pity that for some reason the filter does not apply when I render the map in 3D using ol-cesium.

Comment: It would be great if someone else proposed an alternative solution that were compatible with ol-cesium.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike's [suggestion](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/semi-transparent-layer.html), I have reached this:

JS:

```
var polygonLayer = new LayerVector({
    className: 'geometry-layer',
    source: new SourceVector({
        overlaps: false,
        features: mypolygons
})};
map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
```

CSS:

```
.geometry-layer {
    filter: blur(20px);
}
```

This is looking way better now:

[image]

The only downside of this approach is that it doesn't seem to apply when I render the map in 3D using ol-cesium:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ol-cesium, but as far as I could get from docs, map is first created with OL in 2d and then processed with ol-cesioum for 3d.

If that's true then polygon layer could be blurred within OL with layer `postreneder` event processing function, so it's blurred before being processed with ol-cesium. Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var polygonLayer = new LayerVector({
  source: new SourceVector({
    overlaps: false,
    features: mypolygons
  }
)};
polygonLayer.on('postrender', function (e) {
  e.context.filter = "blur(20px)";
});
map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, in openlayers/2D mode, this blurs both the geometry and the map underneath. And in ol-cesium/3D, there is no filtering at all of either geometry or imagery.